# como mostrar una lista con una estructura maestro-detalle MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Se desea mostrar todos los detalles de un determinado proyecto, para ello se tienen las siguientes tablas

[image: Mestro-Detalle]

en la tabla Salidas se guardan los encabezados (proyectos) y en la tabla SalidasDetalles se guardan los detalles (lista de productos de distintos proyectos)

Se tiene la siguiente vista para que el usuario ingrese el nombre del proyecto y se despleguen los distintos detalles para ese proyecto haciendo click en el boton

[image: View]

com puedo pasarle una lista de SalidasDetalles a mi vista "CierreProyecto.cshtml"?
por ejemplo en la primera imagen si el usuario ingresa el proyecto Kn_CodigoProyecto = 3, se me tienen que desplegar los detalles Kn_CodigoSalidaDetalle = 2,3,4,5

Si bien obtengo los ID´S de la tabla Salida como se muestra en al siguiente figura

[image: listamaestro]

Como puedo buscar esos ID´S en mi tabla SalidasDetalles y mostrarlos en mi vista?

Mis ActionResults:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CierreProyecto(int? page)
        {           
            ViewBag.Kn_CodigoProyecto = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetProyectos(), "Kn_CodigoProyecto", "v_Nombre");

            var view = db.SalidaDetalles.ToList();
            view.Clear();
            return View(view.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 50));           
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CierreProyecto(int? page, string searchTerm)
        {
            List<SalidaDetalle> resultado;

            //consulto codigo proyecto
            var codigoproyecto = db.Proyectos.Where(n => n.v_Nombre == searchTerm).Select(c => c.Kn_CodigoProyecto).FirstOrDefault();

            //consulto en que maestro esta el proyecto ingresado por usuario
            var listamaestro = db.Salidas.Where(c => c.Kn_CodigoProyecto == codigoproyecto).Select(c => c.Kn_CodigoSalida).ToList();

            foreach(var item in listamaestro)
            {
                resultado = db.SalidaDetalles.Where(c => c.Kn_CodigoSalida == listamaestro).ToList();
            }

            ViewBag.Kn_CodigoProyecto = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetProyectos(), "Kn_CodigoProyecto", "v_Nombre");

            return View(resultado.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 50));          
        }
```

View:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IPagedList<SistemaBodega.Models.SalidaDetalle>

<h2>Cerrar Proyecto</h2>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CierreProyecto", "Salidas", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">        

            <hr />

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Proyecto</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtSearch", placeholder = "Nombre Proyecto" })

                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="mybtn" type="submit">
                        Buscar Proyecto
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    }

    <hr />

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center">Codigo</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Producto</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Cantidad</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@item.Kn_CodigoProducto </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@item.v_Nombre</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@item.d_Cantidad</th>                  
                </tr>             
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Se que el foreach esta haciendo algo mal, Como puedo mostrar al usuario la lista de productos de un determinado proyecto? Alguna ayuda para mi?

Answer (score 1):

Esta linea no tiene sentido:

```
   resultado = db.SalidaDetalles.Where(c => c.Kn_CodigoSalida == listamaestro).ToList();
```

Pues listamaestro una linea mas arriba es un conjunto de datos

```
 foreach(var item in listamaestro)
```

En todo caso sera listamaestro.ALGO, pero igualar un codigo a un conjunto de datos no me cuadra, no sé si por ahí va tu error.